# Url management with Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii-url-manager

I have a problem with Yii2's urlManager. I have an action with url `category/index`, where I pass `?par=test` as param.

I want to create an alias for my url so that when `par` is not specified the url will be `/test`, but when it is specified the url should be `/test/some-value`. Here is my config for now:

```
       'rules' => [
            [
                'pattern' => 'test',
                'route'   => 'category/index',
            ],
            '<subcats: (val|some-value)>' => 'test/<subcats>',
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need url like `category/index/test/some-value`. Use that

```
'category/index/test/<val:\w+>' => 'category/index'
```

In controller in method `index` use that:

```
public function actionIndex($val){
```

Yii2 automatically provide parameter `$val` in action.